# Generation of a DAG with a certain number of vertices (java)

Tags: java, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

for an experiment i need to generate a couple of random directed acyclic graphs with a certain amount of vertices (10, 20, 30, 40,50, etc.). 
Does anyone know a good approach for that? For my purpose i use JAVA but the algorithm can be of course either in pseudo code or any C-like language.

Comment: What do you have so far? If you only need a DAG with no additional properties then a basic algorithm should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-to-generate-random-directed-acyclic-graphs) contains a very useful suggestion: DAGs are those with a lower triangular adjacency matrix. So, given an arbitrary ordering of nodes, flip a coin to decide if each link from a node to a successive one exists.